# How do I iterate through an int

Tags: java

I get an "int cannot be dereferenced" It might be because .lenght on it, What else can I do to iterate through the int?

```
int num;

System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
num = console.nextInt();

if (num > 0)
for (int i = 0; i < num.lenght; i++)
System.out.println();
```

Comment: what do you mean if `i=5`, then does you want `i` reach to like `1` as 1 length or `5` as val. ? like wise for `i=10` then `10` or `2`.!!

Comment: What did you expect the "length" a number to be anyway?

Answer (score 9):

`for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`

Your `num` already is a number. So your condition will suffice like above.

*Example:* If the user enters `4`, the for statement will evaluate to
`for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`, running the loop four times, with `i` having the values `0, 1, 2` and `3`

---

If you wanted to iterate over each digit, you would need to turn your [int back to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930210/java-int-to-string-integer-tostringi-vs-new-integeri-tostring) first, and then [loop over each character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a) in this string:

```
String numberString = Integer.toString(num);

for (int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++){
    char c = numberString.charAt(i);        
    //Process char
}
```

---

If you wanted to iterate the *binary representation* of your number, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480375/iterating-bits-of-a-char) question, it might help you.

---

*Note:* though it might not be required, I would suggest you to use `{}`-brackets around your statement blocks, to improve readability and reduce chance of mistakes like this:

```
if (num > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IntStream.range(0, num).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int num = console.nextInt();
        console.close();
        if (num > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Using **Integer.toString** Method

```java
        int num = 110102;
        String strNum = Integer.toString(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < strNum.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(strNum.charAt(i));
        }
```

2. Using **Modulo** Operator
   `

```java
    int num = 1234;
    while(num>0) {
       int remainder = num % 10;
       System.out.println(remainder);
       num = num / 10;    
    }
```